# OpenHab build failed with Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, openhab

I am trying to set OpenHab IDE using the link:
https://github.com/openhab/openhab/wiki/IDE-Setup

I tryied the pure eclipse instraction but my build have failed announcing this error:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.savage7.maven.plugins:maven-external-dependen
cy-plugin:0.4:resolve-external (resolve-install-external-dependencies) on projec
t org.openhab.io.multimedia.tts.marytts: Read timed out -> [Help 1]

I use Maven 3.3.1

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Actually the cause of the problem is that the hardware target was not successfully set.